# PWA Splash Screen Icon Size is too big

Tags: progressive-web-apps, splash-screen

I succeed pwa(twa) app deploy google play store. but i faced the problem that pwa splash screen icon is too big when download application on google play store then launched app. How handle this? i used pwabuilder tool(MS Tool) that convert apk.
i think manifest is no problem. because add to home is works fine. splash screen is works. But only problem is pwa app downloaded from google play store.
any advice welcome.

```
// manifest.json
{
  "short_name": "My",
  "name": "My",
  "description": "My App",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "android-chrome-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "android-chrome-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem, and my TWA can not be launched in fullscreen (immersive mode)

Comment: IMO the problem is that PWABuilder uses sizes to determine which image to use when there should be another way to say "use this for splash screen and this for desktop icons". Vote up https://github.com/pwa-builder/PWABuilder/issues/3559 if you agree.

Answer (score 1):

Just to generate the apk, don't change the image file size, but decrease the useful part of your logo. Save and generate the APK, then return the image the way it was for your PWA to work better.